# How much do the first seven exposed cards in a game of Klondike Solitaire have a bearing on the eventual outcome?

Tags: probability, card-games

In a standard game of Klondike Solitaire ( patience), seven cards are exposed at the start of the game. I have been playing a lot of it recently, thanks to Covid 19, and try and work out, from the outset, if I am more or less likely than usual to be successful.
Work by an organisation called "Jupiter Scientific" has estimated that some 43% of hands are winnable. They have used thousands of Monte Carlo simulations to arrive at this figure, and admit that the average 'recreational player' is likely to be much less successful than this ( its about 25% in my own case ).

Clearly, any aces dealt face up at the outset, give you a head start ( especially if they appear to the right hand side of the tableau). But is the inverse true - ie are Kings necessarily a bad thing?

I have an inkling, but it is no more than that, that having two cards of the same rank and color ( ie a 9 of hearts and the 9 of diamonds ) can also be bad thing. If you do not have a black 8 in the remaining deck you are blocked in two columns, until one is overturned in the tableau.

What other "clues" are there at the outset, or is it the case that the opening, exposed cards, aren't that important?
Another important factor will be if a card can immediately be moved to another column. This is particularly true for the final two columns of the tableau. In "winnable deals" these occured 20% more often than with "random deals" in a solitaire playing app.

Comment: Typically the only card that can be placed in an empty column is a King ... so a King may not be the worst card as a Queen may be even worse.  But yes, two cards of the same rank and color is clearly not a good thing.  Don't think you'll get any exact answers though: there are just too many possible games here and the math is too ugly. In fact, the exact percentage of some hands being winnable also depends on what the perfect strategy is, and even that is really hard to compute, as you'd need to take into the account the probability of certain cards showing up when you make certain moves.

Comment: So, the only feasible way to get some rough idea is to employ a 'pretty good game-playing strategy' (one that, for example, takes careful account of how you pick cards from the pile, given that you go through the pile 3 cards at a time), and then do a whole lot of simulations. And then you can see if indeed getting two cards with the same rank and order will have a significant effect on the outcome. My bet is that if you indeed get a bunch of those 'bad' cards initially, it would have a 'significant' effect ... but that's just a bet.

Comment: Good point about queens clearly being worse than kings, but this is obviously all speculation. The mathematician Persi Diaconis has said that "the inability of theoreticians to precisely calculate these odds is one of the embarrassments of applied probability"

Comment: Yes, it's just infeasible to calculate this: you'd need to know the best strategy in order to calculate the odds, and you'd need to know the odds to calculate the best strategy. Nice quote :)

Comment: I agree with all the comments so far, and would like to add small insight, on how you could, again just theoretically, exactly measure the impact of opening. For each opening you count the number of winnable hands with exactly that opening (that is, you permute all other hidden cards and count how many winnable hands you have). Then, you draw a histogram of number of winnable hands and observe the curve. High variance means that opening matters a lot. This would not answer what "clues" are there in outset, rather just the second part "how important is the opening".

Comment: I have downloaded a solitaire playing app that gives the option of playing "winnable deals" or "random deals". By observing the different starting hands of each ( 200 trials) I have observed the following results. Aces in winnable deals outnumber random deals by 11% ( as one might expect,) but 2's outnumbered them by 44%. Same rank and color cards appeared 22% less in "winnable deals". Oddly, Queens appeared in the first two columns of winnable deals almost twice as often as in random deals ( with hardly any difference in the other columns.)